# MaterializeCSS Framework Modals

Tags: modal-dialog, materialize

I'm using materializecss.com Framework. I want to create a modal. I looked in the documentation (http://materializecss.com/modals.html), how to create a modal. I created a modal like the documentation it explains...

```
   <!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal bottom-sheet">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

but if i click the button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

To open a modal using a trigger you must Initialize the modal;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x067vq5c/)